# Jmeter - How do I see sampler data following running a test from Command line?

Tags: command-line, jmeter, automated-tests, resultset

I have a test which I have successfully run manually and am confident that it runs correctly.

I am now converting it to run via linux command line by parameterising it.

The test completes successfully and I'm successfully storing the 'Results Tree' and on opening the stored 'Results Tree' file I can see all tests have passed.

However, I cannot see any of the sampler data, which is making me deeply suspicious that the tests are not actually being run, merely that the requests are being sent and returned with the correct return code.

I need to be able to prove that certain values are being extracted and tested.

I tried inserting a Beanshell Post Processor but this generated more warning and error messages than it provided useful information.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, JMeter doesn't store response data to avoid disk IO overhead as in case of high loads and large responses it may be a bottleneck which will ruin your test.

If you need to enable it for some reason, you can add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

Another way of one-time ad-hoc properties change is passing them via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

UPD: if you need request data along with request and response headers:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

Comment: How do I then view the sample data in relation to the test they were produced from?